# Unity 3d movement not working with Camera direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts one is the MouseHandler and the other is the SimpleMovement. rotating the camera works and moving works however when the camera turns the movement doesn't go in that direction. E.G i turn the camera 90 degrees to the right but the forward doesn't change. The forward doesn't go to where the camera is facing. Sorry if i'm just being stupid. Any help would be appreciated

MouseHandler script:

```
public class MouseHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // horizontal rotation speed
    public float horizontalSpeed = 1f;
    // vertical rotation speed
    public float verticalSpeed = 1f;
    private float xRotation = 0.0f;
    private float yRotation = 0.0f;
    private Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSpeed;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSpeed;

        yRotation += mouseX;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

        cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

SimpleMovement Script:

```
public class SimpleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;
    public float MovementSpeed = 1;
    public float Gravity = 9.8f;
    private float velocity = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // player movement - forward, backward, left, right
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MovementSpeed;
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MovementSpeed;
        characterController.Move((Vector3.right * horizontal + Vector3.forward * vertical) * Time.deltaTime);

        // Gravity
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            velocity = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            characterController.Move(new Vector3(0, velocity, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get a reference to the main cmaera and cache it, because you're going to be referencing it frequently, and simply using `Camera.main` is a bit expensive:

```
private Camera mainCam;

...

private void Start()
{
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}
```

Then, use `mainCam.transform.right` and `mainCam.transform.forward` but with the `y` set to 0 and normalized instead of `Vector3.right` and `Vector3.forward`. This will make the movement be based on the rotation of the camera:

```
float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MovementSpeed;
float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MovementSpeed;
Vector3 camRightFlat = new Vector3(mainCam.transform.right.x, 0f, 
        mainCam.transform.right.z).normalized;
Vector3 camForwardFlat = new Vector3(mainCam.transform.forward.x, 0f,
        mainCam.transform.forward.z).normalized;
characterController.Move(
        (camRightFlat * horizontal + camForwardFlat  * vertical) * Time.deltaTime);
```

Altogether:

```
public class SimpleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;
    public float MovementSpeed = 1;
    public float Gravity = 9.8f;
    private float velocity = 0;
    private Camera mainCam;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        mainCam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // player movement - forward, backward, left, right
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MovementSpeed;
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MovementSpeed;
        Vector3 camRightFlat = new Vector3(mainCam.transform.right.x, 0f, 
                mainCam.transform.right.z).normalized;
        Vector3 camForwardFlat = new Vector3(mainCam.transform.forward.x, 0f, 
                mainCam.transform.forward.z).normalized;
        characterController.Move((camRightFlat * horizontal + camForwardFlat  * vertical) 
                * Time.deltaTime);

        // Gravity
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            velocity = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            characterController.Move(new Vector3(0, velocity, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So that did work well so then i added a body.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0.0f); to the mousehandler script so the body would turn as the camera turns however this has shown another problem, i added a gun model to the player and as i turn the gun does move round with the player and it tunrs however it has this like ghosting effect, do you know why? It looks really bad.

Comment: @Cole_8910 Answering the question above and solving this "ghosting effect" is too broad for a single answer. Consider [asking another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and including a [mre] that will produce the ghosting effect.